# Impedance simulation using Pspice

Tags: pspice

I am trying to simulate the equivalent circuit of an inductor using pspice 9.1. I need to plot its impedance vs frequency to observe the parasitic behavior. I am new to pspice and I don't know how to simulate the Impedance vs Frequency. The circuit is shown below : [image]

Comment: I've never used PSpice but I'm certain there's probably a way create your own parameters when performing some simulations, i.e. the verticle axis can have the variable of voltage divided by current (that would get you the impedance).

Comment: Do not forget to ground one of the outer nodes.

Comment: Apply a AC current to the left side. Ground the right side. Monitor the left side voltage.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I need to monitor the input impedance of the circuit bro not the voltage

Comment: you mean I set the current value to 1 A ?

Comment: You can use the "VAC"/"IAC" sources for frequency analysis

Comment: Yeah, bro, you don't measure impedance directly in SPICE. You apply a known source voltage/current, measure the resulting current/voltage, and calculate the impedance.